# Is there a way to modify a class without inheriting it?

Tags: vb.net

Lets say i have ClassA which i do have acces to the source code but limited availability to modify it (without a good reason because its active in Production).

i have a LibraryX that calls ClassA's method.

i have a unit testing module that calls LibraryX in a test environment without many of the necessary accesses to the various DBs and files needed.
I would like to stub the methods without changing the original's code (or a minimum of interventions)

Like Shadowing/overriding the methods WITHOUT being inherited... because if i inherit and test the inherited class... i'm no longer testing the base class...

Comment: Look into mocking frameworks. Though you will soon find, that unless you are testing against interfaces, these frameworks use inheritance as well to stub the methods.

Comment: Can you explain a little more, maybe provide an example of what you mean? Not sure what you mean when you say you want to change stuff without changing stuff because "i'm no longer testing the base class". What stuff are you changing then? Do you need to just ADD some new methods that will be used for unit testing?

Answer (score 0):

You say that you have limited access to changing the code in ClassA because it's used in production.

What you could do if you're allowed is to extract all the methods in CLassA into an Interface,  then let ClassA implement that interface.

You could use the interface to stub out the methods using a mocking framework.

This way the production should not be affected except that ClassA now implements the interface. The code in production still have access to all the ClassA's properties or methods.

With this method you have two ways to access ClassA:

1. Via ClassA  ( dim _classA As New ClassA() )   as it probably is today
2. Via the interface  ( dim _classA As IClassA = new ClassA() )

This is the way I would solved this task.
Hope this helps you